WatchOS Fall Detection Consequences
My team and I are working on an app for a private emergency helpline.
Now as far as I understand the (sparse) API documentation for fall detection, given the appropriate entitlement, the following happens upon a detected fall:
The Standard UI will be opened with the options to a) call SOS b) acknowledge the fall but state that you're fine though, c) deny the fall, and (implicitly after 60 seconds on inactivity) call SOS because you didn't react.
All fall detection apps will then receive a bit of background time and get the func fallDetectionManager(CMFallDetectionManager, didDetect: CMFallDetectionEvent, completionHandler: () -> Void) called with the appropriate event value.
Now that's all good and it sounds like the custom fall detection is additive to the standard system.
But but why is there something like that in the entitlement request form sheet:

For any emergency calling features that you do not provide, explain any mitigations you use to make sure the user receives emergency services support that’s as close as possible to what they’d receive had they placed an emergency call natively.

This sounds like our app would rather be a drop-in to the standard SOS service ­– in contrast to being additive and also in contrast to what the API documentation infers.
Am I misunderstanding something?
